# Meeting walks on directed graphs

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

Consider a directed graph $G = (V,A)$. For every vertex $v \in V$ we have $d$ directed edges out of $v$, which we'll denote $v(1), v(2), \dots, v(d)$.

Given a sequence $i_1, i_2, \dots, i_\ell \in \{1, 2, \dots, d\}$ and a starting vertex $v$, there is a length-$\ell$ walk $v_0, v_1, \dots, v_\ell$ defined recursively:

- $v_0 = v$.
- for $1 \le k \le \ell$, from $v_{k-1}$, we take edge $v_{k-1}(i_k)$, and call its target $v_k$.

The question is: when can we guarantee that for any two vertices $x,y \in V$ there is a sequence $i_1, i_2, \dots, i_\ell \in \{1, 2, \dots, d\}$ such that the walks $x_0, x_1, \dots, x_\ell$ and $y_0, y_1, \dots, y_\ell$ meet (that is, such that $x_\ell = y_\ell$)?

Comment: How do the indices $i_1, i_2, \dots$ affect the walk you take? You have not used them in any way in your statement.

Comment: $i_1, ...$ describe our walk. So if you are at node $x$ given tthe sequence $i_1, i_2,...$ you walk along edge $i_2$ then at your new node along $i_2$. So we want to find a "walk" $i_1, i_2,...$ such that starting at $x$ and $y$ gives us the same result...

Comment: I've edited your question to, hopefully, clarify this. (You can of course revert if you don't like the change.) Note that I made an assumption about the order of quantifiers ($\forall x,y \in V\; \exists \ell, i_1, i_2, \dots, i_\ell$) but actually the reverse order $\exists \ell, i_1, i_2, \dots, i_\ell \text{ s.t. } \forall x,y \in V$ is equivalent.

Comment: Thx! That's exactly what I meant... So hopefully someone has an idea :-)

In fact this unsolved problem seems to be the same: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1914222/finding-meeting-points-in-graph

Ahhh, of course the graph should be strongly connected, but I think thats of course necessary. I think it is not a bad idea to also assume aperiodicity

Comment: A suitable (non-empty) graph $G$ cannot be bipartite.